# Overheating - What's a suitable minimum and maximum temperature for a desktop system?

Tags: overheating, desktop-apps

As a newbie to Ubuntu 15.10 and Linux, does it make sense for me to use the following apps, to reduce overheating and/or to monitor more closely my system temperature?

1. TLP
2. CPUFREQ

[image: psensor temperature of system image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [xsensors](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/xsensors/) which is available via Ubuntu software center. I also have Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS installed on a Desktop(Quad Core) and i use it to sometimes monitor CPU/core temperatures and also fan.
Here are some of the sample images from my system.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank so much for the speedy reply. I really appreciate the feedback. I installed xsensors 0.70 via the software centre. See 3 screen shots attached. Oops, I'm not allowed to inbed images as yet.  But let me describe them:

1. radeon: 48 C - that's quite hight isn't it?
2. coretemp: 34 - 36 C
3.  asus - cpu fan - 0 RPM - does that mean it is off?

PS. my system is an ASUS desktop computer and not a laptop

Comment: I live in Phoenix AZ area which is generally higher temperature during summer(around 110 Degree F). For my desktop the CPU temperature hasn't gone above 40 degree celsius even in peak summer. If it goes above 50 degree celsius then i need to start worrying...i read in one of the hardware forum that anything beyond 60 degree celsius is not a good sign. If you are okay with the answer kindly accept it and tick mark it.

Answer (score 1):

For intel CPUs a safe maximum is anything below 100°C
For AMD CPUs a safe maximum is anything below 80°C
For most GPUs a safe maximum is anything below 84°C
It is however recommended to keep your hardware running below that temperature.
Do not worry though, your hardware will not break from overheating, it is designed to thermal-throttle when it reaches its safe maximum.

Answer (score 0):

If the temperature is above 27°C it can be detrimental for your computer. And your CPU should not be hotter than 75°C since it could damage the components. 
Using **tlp**, which is an advanced power management for Linux helps to save the battery life to a great extent. If you don't have an advanced graphics card, probably you don't have to worry about heating issue unless there is a defect in your CPU fan.